# What else to return when there is only one thing to return?

Tags: c#, wpf, return

```
public static Window GetMainWindow()
     {
        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
            {
                return (window as MainWindow);
            }
        }
        return new Window(); //useless?
     }
```

As you can see I return the MainWindow from my application, which will always work. If I don't add the `return new Window()` then it obviously complains about not all code paths returning a value. Now my question is, is there a better way to solve this, as I feel like returning a new Window is pretty useless?

Thanks

Comment: Throw an exception. If you expect that the loop will always find the window and somehow it doesn't, it will let you know in spectacular fashion that something seriously wrong happened.

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev If you want to have good code, is this acceptable? Because if it is then it's all good.

Comment: Why just don't use `Application.Current.MainWindow` and check it for a `null` value?

Comment: Doubtful... a NullReferenceException will happen when you try to use the result and the root cause will be harder to track down.

Comment: It should be `return Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;` and the result should of course be checked for `null` after the method call.

Comment: returning `return Application.Current.MainWindow` works. But out of curiousity, if you can't do something like that and need a foreach loop, then is returning null a good idea?

Comment: Do you intend to call `GetMainWindow` before the main window is created or after it's destroyed?

Comment: @madreflection I use a splashscreen, so the `MainWindow `is hidden until the splashscreen is done with its code, then it hides and the `MainWindow `gets shown again. In other words, the method gets called when the `MainWindow` is still hidden.

Comment: So... no. Then I think it's safe to say that the expectation is that the main window will always exist when `GetMainWindow` is called. Thus, don't return null. Throw an exception because it's *exceptional*. Let it die a horrible death so you know to fix the problem instead of letting it silently not work or throw unrelated exceptions that are harder to track down (e.g. NullReferenceException).

Comment: I would even go so far as to define a custom exception for this so that there's absolutely no question that it's this exact problem that occurred. *"Unhandled `MainWindowNotFoundException`? I know exactly where that happened!"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may return `null` or throw an `Exception`.

Additionally I've found a redundant type cast `Window` to `MainWindow` in your code. In case of returning `Window` Type you don't need it. Let's return `MainWindow` instead.

```cs
public static MainWindow GetMainWindow()
{
    var mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow;

    // Optional if block that checks for null and throws an exception.
    //
    if (mainWindow == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("MainWindow not found");
    }

    return mainWindow;
}
```

Comment: Also choose a more specifc exception type, either a custom exception or perhaps InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @Clemens Agree, thank you for edit. By the way, preferred was to stay close to OP's code.

Comment: OP's code was nonsense. Better show how it should *actually* be done. You may also put even more emphasis on the point that both approaches - returning null and throwing an exception - are perfectly valid, and none is "better" in any way. It totally depends on the application logic which one to choose.

Comment: Roger. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As your method is called `GetMainWindow`, then other people could think that intention of this method method is to return `MainWindow`, otherwise `MainWindow` is not found. It is not [a factory method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350692/what-else-to-return-when-there-is-only-one-thing-to-return/60351172?noredirect=1#comment106775355_60351172) which should create some object and return it.

So it is better to throw an exception if `MainWindow` is not found.

There is a good article that say that it is better to throw an exception when things go wrong because it [is easier to determine what kind of error is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/exceptions-as-repackaged-error-codes):

> The good news for the "System.Exception as an uber error code" is that
>   it's relatively easy to determine what kind of error failed from the
>   strong type information that the CLR provides, which means that the
>   "deconstruct the rich information into a simpler version" pattern I
>   just mentioned isn't likely to happen.

Comment: @downvoter what's reason to downvote? It would be really helpful to know what aspect should be improved in my reply. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a downvoter but guessing that it was because you didn't answered the OP's question but suggested to read something about excepions without any reason. I upvoted your answer because it may be useful in current context. Thank you for the link.